# JavaFX 2 embed YouTube video

Tags: java, webview, youtube, javafx-2

Is there a way to embed a YouTube video with JavaFX 2 without a WebView? And if using a WebView is the only viable option, how can I detect when a video started and ended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to embed a YouTube video with JavaFX 2 without a WebView?

Technically, probably yes, but legally no as that would require using a video player other than the YouTube video player, which would violate [YouTube's current terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms).

If instead, you embed a player in JavaFX using a WebView to display YouTube's HTML5 embedded player, then that is ok with the YouTube terms of service agreement.

> how can I detect when a video started and ended?

Use the [YouTube JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status) to monitor playback status.